# If users have messages between them and a user deletes his account, the other user can no longer access the messages index in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I followed a tutorial to allow users to send each other messages on my app. I'm using devise for authentication. Basically if two or more users have conversations between them and one or more cancels their account, the remaining can no longer access the index page for conversations. I get `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` in `ConversationsController#index`.

The code in bold is where the error was identified. What would be the best way to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Index view:

```
<% @conversations.each do |conversation| %>
  <% if conversation.sender_id == current_user.id || conversation.recipient_id == current_user.id %>
    <% if conversation.sender_id == current_user.id %>
      **<% recipient = User.find(conversation.recipient_id) %>**
    <% else %>
      <% recipient = User.find(conversation.sender_id) %>
    <% end %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to (image_tag recipient.avatar.url, size: "50x50"), user_path(recipient) %></td>
      <td><%= recipient.full_name %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "View Message", conversation_messages_path(conversation) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end%>
```

The Controller:

```
 class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
   def index
     @users = User.all
     @conversations = Conversation.all
   end

  def create
   if Conversation.between(params[:sender_id],params[:recipient_id])
     .present?
      @conversation = Conversation.between(params[:sender_id],
       params[:recipient_id]).first
   else
    @conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)
   end
   redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
  end

  private
   def conversation_params
    params.permit(:sender_id, :recipient_id)
   end
  end
```

The Model:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, :foreign_key => :sender_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, :foreign_key => :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'

  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy

  validates_uniqueness_of :sender_id, :scope => :recipient_id

  scope :between, -> (sender_id,recipient_id) do
    where("(conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?) OR (conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?)", sender_id,recipient_id, recipient_id, sender_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: You should post your controller & model as well. Posting the index view itself does not help people spot what the error may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it's a problem, and you have a lot of calls that are made on the non-existent user records.

I'd suggest you replace...

```
recipient = User.find(conversation.recipient_id)
```

and

```
recipient = User.find(conversation.sender_id)
```

with...

```
recipient = get_the_user(conversation.recipient_id)
recipient = get_the_user(conversation.sender_id)
```

You'll need a helper method... you can put it in your `ApplicationController`

```
class ApplicationController

  helper_method :get_the_user

  DummyUser= Struct.new(:full_name)

  def get_the_user(id)
    user = User.find_by(id: id)
    return user if user
    user = DummyUser.new('deleted user')
  end
```

And as you can't link to the nonexistent user, change

```
 <%= link_to (image_tag recipient.avatar.url, size: "50x50"), user_path(recipient) %>
```

into

```
 <%= recipient.class == User ? link_to (image_tag recipient.avatar.url, size: "50x50"), user_path(recipient) : 'no link available' %>
```

Comment: Btw @Maurice this is solution (1) in my answer. I don't say it is wrong, it is a perfect example of doing things differently - Depending on what you want and need. In this case: If a user is unhappy with your service and cancels his account, his messages are not deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want:

1. User should be marked as "deleted", but message is readable.
2. If one of the users is deleted, message will be destroyed too.
3. Message is not readable for users, but admins... (worst idea I could think of)

Imo (2) is the way to go. `User` Model should have something like:

```
 has_many :conversations, dependent: :destroy
```

And imo your question is more fundamental than you think. Software-Development is often more about making decisions than writing code.

Comment: I tried solution number 2 but that doesn't work either :-(

Comment: Did you reset your testdata? (Of course this will not work, if the conversation, which relates to a deleted object still exists)

Comment: That's what I thought as well and tried it, but it didn't work. The solution provided by @steveturczyn worked, just had to tweak it a bit